# How can I detect USB gamepad input in Mono/C#?

Tags: c#, input, mono

I've used DirectInput for gamepad input in the past when coding for Windows (Microsoft Visual Studio C#), but now I'm trying to code for ubuntu using Mono, and it's a little more difficult. I can't see how I would grab such input.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for detecting hot plugged or scanning already plugged devices to obtain, for example, its device path and then doing whatever you need with it, I once did it using halsharp project. It seemed dead, nevertheless worked. Now, with HAL deprecated, you may be interested in [this](https://launchpad.net/gudev-sharp) project.